# How to create new window/form in MonoTouch/MonoDevelop/Interface Builder. (Mac)

Tags: macos, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have created my first application in MonoDevelop. I'm having difficulty to create a second window (form).

- If I create a new UIView it has .cs and .designer.cs files attached to it. It looks good, but it doesn't have appdelegate to attach events to.
- If I use the new UIWindow I don't have .cs and .designer.cs files attached to it. And I don't have delegates either.
- If I copy the original MainWindow and rename it, it almost works, I have delegate and .designer.cs but it complains about duplicating certain objects. Like "Window", "AppDelegate"

So how am I supposed to create some new forms that needs some buttons and events to deal with?

Answer (score 0):

In an iPhone app, you should generally only have 1 window.

Create a new UIViewController with your desired elements, and present it as a "modal" view controller over your other controllers.  It will function similar to ShowDialog(), except it won't be a blocking call.

The methods are PresentModalViewController() and DismissModalViewControllerAnimated().

Here is a decent [example](http://pastebin.com/h221BQdK).